# DAX to get countrows or sum of a category per year and month

Tags: dax, powerbi-desktop

I am getting stuck in using DAX and Managing relationship.

Goal: Count all valid redlights (categorized by YES) per year then month

Pictures

[This is the KPI table (OE,LINES,RL,FPY, TAT) and DAX where I need to put the count. As of the moment, the count is incorrect. Since we are only on Period 8, there should be no data on Period 9-12 yet. Also, the count should be PD1=1, PD2=0, PD3=1, PD4=1 and so on... the total valid RL for 2023 should be 6.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Lw3a.png)

The redlight count came from "REDLIGHT TABLE".
The date that is being used as a slicer for the charts came from CRM Activity Table.

[Here is my latest relationship table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oeEPH.png)

Issue: I am getting there but it always gets the sum of all the years in Redlight table per month. So instead of having the sum of 2023 Period 1, I am getting the sum of 2021 - 2023 Period 1.

I've been remodeling the relationship, but I can't get any progress.

Comment: Goal: Count all valid redlights (categorized by YES) per year then month
COUNTROWS( FILTER('RedLightsTable',[Category]="Yes'))
Then just add year and month from Calendar table on rows or columns and then add the measure

COUNTROWS

Comment: if the measure isn't respecting the Date filters, then I have to ask, are you using the Calendar/Date table in your rows/columns? you *should* be able to use a MonthYear column (or first of month) to get the totals you want.
If that doesn't help, could you post another diagram of the fact table and the calendar table? Maybe I'm missing something in the relationship.

Comment: I am using the Date from the Redlight table but the KPI table only does have PD01 to PD12 and the Year columns. Am I missing important? Can you help me figure out what should be added? Should I make another column for the equivalent month per period with the year on them?

Comment: I would absolutely recommend creating a Calendar table for this and joining that to your RedLight fact table. then you can roll up the counts on that table pretty much any way you want (well, that the Calendar table will support).
Trying to create a design with multiple fact tables before you really understand DAX well is going to make you miserable. (Maybe reading the first few chapters of Ralph Kimball's Data Warehouse Toolkit will help ... if nothing else, he knows how to design a proper data warehouse.

Comment: I still don't get it. I'm going crazy.

Comment: can you post some data somewhere? (with your data model).